# Laravel:¿Cómo puedo guardar una imagen en base 64 en la base de datos?

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, imagen

**Resulta que tengo el siguiente código para hacer un update en laravel con query builder**.

```
 public function editarCedente(Request $request)
    {
        $id_cedente_e = $request->id_cedente_edit;
        $nombre_cedente_e = $request->edit_nombre_cede;
        $path = $request->file('edita_imagen_cedente');
        $imagen_cedente_e = File::get($path);
        //llamo a la funcion estatica de un archivo que he creado 
        //para el Procedimiento alamacenado
        $edita_cedente = S_Update_Cedente::get_update_cedente($id_cedente_e,$nombre_cedente_e,base64_encode($imagen_cedente_e));
        return redirect()->route('cedentes');
    }
```

**Este es la función estática**

```
public static function get_update_cedente($id_cedente_e,$nombre_cedente_e,$imagen_cedente_e)
{
     $update_cedente = DB::select('exec S_Update_Cedente '.$id_cedente_e.', "'.$nombre_cedente_e.'", "'.$imagen_cedente_e.'" ');

  return $update_cedente;
}
```

**El error que me da es el siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonce no se que  podrá ser si estoy haciendo algo mal o necesito otra forma de hacer esto, los tipos de datos serian los siguientes en la base de datos `sql server:`

- *id_cedente* tipo `int`.
- *nombre_cedente*  tipo `varchar`.
- *imagen_cedente* tipo `image`

> PD: es un requerimeinto guardalo en base 64 en la base de datos ,
>   también pensé en guardar solo la url de la imagen.

Comment: yo guardaria las imagenes en el servidor, y la direccion de esa imagen la guardaria en la bd

Comment: @x-rw en el pd puse que ese es el requerimiento , si yo quería guardar la url en la bd y el archivo en  alguna carpeta del servidor.

Comment: podrías pegar todo el mensaje de error entero?

Comment: lo que pasa que el resto es puros caracteres nada mas, por eso puse lo que creo que importaba.

Comment: bueno de todas maneras es probable que sea un tema de comillas o comillas dobles en el stored procedure, podes probar agregandole SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF; al principio a ver si se te resuelve el problema

Comment: donde pongo eso @LeonardoCabré ? en que parte de mi codigo?

Comment: al principio del stored procedure, o no tenes acceso a él (S_Update_Cedente )?

Comment: en el `use` o depues del begin?, creo que encontre el error es  `is too long. Maximum length is 128`

Comment: antes del use, en la primera linea antes de cualquier cosa. Adicionalmente podrias poner el codigo del stored procedure en tu pregunta para poder ojearlo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Por las comillas dobles te está tomando los datos como un identificador (nombre de tabla o columna según el contexto) y como el base64 es muy grande salta ese error (identifier mu grande), si la imagen fuera pequeña te daría el error "invalid column name" por ejemplo el base64 de un gif transparente: `R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7` puede ser usado como nombre de tabla/columna pero en este esquema no se encontraría.

podes probar usando single quotes

```
$update_cedente = DB::select(
  'exec S_Update_Cedente '.$id_cedente_e.', "'.$nombre_cedente_e.'", ' .
  " '". $imagen_cedente_e. "'");
```

o llamando al procedure vía parámetros

```
return DB::select(
    'call S_Update_Cedente(?,?,?)',
     array($id_cedente_e, $nombre_cedente_e,$imagen_cedente_e);
);
```

o como señalan en los comentarios desactivar `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` en el SQL
cómo y donde desactivarlo dependerá del store procedure para ejemplo te dejo un fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11d01

en la pagina de msdn hay un ejemplo de combinar el `ON` y el `OFF`

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql

Comment: mañana lo probare y te avisaré si m funcionó.

Answer (score 2):

Yo maneje subir fotos de esta manera:

Ve a este link para que instales el Image

http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Después lo implemente de esta forma

En la controller:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

if($request->hasFile($request->input('imagen'))){
            $avatar = $request->file('imagen');
            $filename = $input['codigo'] . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->save(public_path('/uploads/productos/'. $filename));

            $input['imagen'] = $filename;
        } else{
            $input['imagen'] = 'default.png';
        }
```

Y en la vista puse un enctype:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'productos.store', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

                        @include('productos.fields')

                    {!! Form::close() !!}

<div>
        <label for="form-field-select-3">Imagen del producto</label>
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="file" id="id-input-file-3" name="imagen" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```